# Which is better for this project, procedural or object oriented?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe2, code-structure, omnithreadlibrary

I've been working through many trial/error versions of an image loading/caching system. Being Delphi, I've always been comfortable with Object Oriented Programming. But since I've started implementing some multi-threading, I've been thinking that maybe this system should work on a procedural basis instead.

Why is because these processes will be kicked into a thread pool, do the dirty loading/saving of images, and free themselves up. I've been trying to wrap these threaded processes inside objects, when I could just use procedures/functions, records, events, and graphics. No need to wrap it all inside a class, when it's all inside a unit... right?

Now one main reason I'm asking is because this system is initialized at the bottom of the unit. When using the OmniThreadLibrary (OTL), it already has its own initialized thread pool, and I don't even need to initialize mine either.

So which approach is better for this system - wrapped inside an object, or just functions within the unit, and why? Any examples of multi-threading without wrapping anything inside an object, but in the unit instead?

Comment: Why would stand-alone records and procedures/functions (which probably work with those records) be better than objects?

Comment: @mghie Memory conservation, avoiding create/free, and I don't need much in the records but the handle, filename, etc. Images which were loaded from threads will be stored in a list temporarily, until acquired by host app. Images will be retrieved by its Handle (or ID). Much easier to work with `Integer` than to work with `TSomeWrapper`. It would actually be more-so like API.

Comment: Memory conservation - who cares about a few extra vtables etc. when you are dealing with images?  Avoiding create/free - use an object pool-quicker than create/free/new/malloc and less contention on the memory-manager, (and easier to detect leaks and provides flow-control).  If you need to list/queue the images, read the images into an image field of the task object and list/queue the task objects when they come back from the pool.  You may have gathered by now that I'm not a great fan of non-OO in an OO-environment but, hey, if it works for you, (for now, anyway:) fine!

Comment: @Jerry: All your arguments fall into the category of micro-optimization, which doesn't make sense once you bring out the big guns like a thread pool. Write it in a way that it's easiest to understand for those concerned. If you are comfortable with OOP, why not use it? There's nothing in your description that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: Surprising amount of answers to a question that is 'not constructive'...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, more surprising is what some people are answering **and** voting to close at the same time as in *half-pregnant*.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a singleton then it boils down to a matter of personal preference. Here are some thoughts of mine:

- If the rest of your codebase uses OOP then use procedural could make this code look and feel odd.
- If you use OOP you can use properties, default properties, array properties. That could make your interface more useable.
- Putting your functionality into a class gives you an extra namespace level. You may or may not appreciate that.
- If you need to maintain a lot of state with global scope then you'll probably wrap it up into a record. And you will have functions that operate on this global record instance. At which point the code would read better written with object syntax.

Bottom line is that it doesn't really matter and you have to pick what fits best in your project.

Comment: +1 Every time I've been tempted to use a struct/record because it's easier/convenient at the time, I've eventually found I needed to call methods on it.  I know that records can have methods now, but I don't see much point.  After decades of OO, I find it very uncomfortable writing stuff in plain C - I can't see what data belongs to what and it's just so.. nasty!  Things get even more dire for non-OO with multithreading - having the data, methods and results fields in one object and queueing it to a thread/pool just seems natural..

Answer (score 1):

OOP doesn't mean you need to create new object for everything. You can simply inherit from existing objects too. (like the whatever thread object of the OTL)

Anyway, I'm not exactly rabid in introducing OO everywhere, but I don't see any reason in your text why procedural would be needed.

Comment: There is no need to inherit from any of the objects in OTL, the library is equally suited to programming in a more functional style, where only free functions or existing object methods are passed for execution.

Comment: @mghie Exactly my point; and I'm also more than familiar with inheriting.

Comment: @Jerry: No, that's not your point. The biggest problem with multi-threading in Delphi, C++, C# and so on is to get the data sharing and object lifetime issues right. If anything I would suggest interfaces over objects.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a yes/no decision by any means.

I tend to use functions and procedures that are not part of classes, when the work they do has nothing to do with any state, and when they are intended to be useful and reused separately, such as is the case for utility string functions in their own utility unit.    You might find you need "Image Utility Functions" and that they do not need to be in a class.

If your function only runs in the context of a background thread, then it probably belongs to a TThread-descendant, and if it's not to be called by the foreground, it can be private, making OOP, and its scope-hiding capabilities very much apropos for thread programming.

My rule of thumb is : If you don't benefit from making it a standalone function/procedure in some real way, then don't go back to non-OOP procedures.

Some people are so into OOP that they avoid non-OOP functions and procedures, and like to have class wrappers for everything. I call that "Java code smell".  But there is no reason to avoid OOP. It's just a tool. Use it where it makes sense.